# How can I fix a Macbook Pro when the Touch Bar doesn't work?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, touch-bar

I have a 13" 2016 Macbook Pro with touchbar and the touchbar is completely disabled.

1. The Touch Bar settings in the keyboard settings are gone 
   [image: Keyboard settings]
2. The touch bar agent in activity monitor is missing. 
   [image: Activity monitor]

The system is running in macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Here's a list of everything I tried:

- I've tried running this in terminal:

  ```
  pkill "Touch Bar agent"; 
  killall "ControlStrip";
  ```

  and

  ```
  sudo pkill "Touch Bar agent"; sudo killall "ControlStrip";
  ```
- Starting in Safe Mode
- SMC reset
- NVRAM reset
- Apple Hardware Test (booting while holding <kbd>D</kbd>), resulting in "No problems found"

However, nothing seems to work.

I don't know what else to do besides a factory reset.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please put this into the terminal

```
sudo pkill "TouchBarServer"
```

it will ask for a password type  it and hit enter it won't show that you are typing the password but it did

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't work

Comment: after killing the TouchBar server, did you reboot and tested?

Comment: Yes, and it's still missing

Comment: what is the version of Mojave you have? Did you try to get the latest supplement update from macstore.

Comment: I have the 10.14.6 version (the latest update). I now noticed that the computer is randomly restarting, and showing "your computer restarted because of a problem". I think it might be related to the touch bar

Comment: at this point with my all experience, I would suggest you reinstall macOS.

Comment: i will try that and let you know if it worked

Comment: I ultimately took it to an apple's "support center" and they fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a slight uptick in these reports at work. We tell people to use the Apple menu to log out, then shut down from the log in screen. Watching that the bar does or does not update itself. Then powering on and testing in a second account if needed.

- [Touch Bar has blank/void button after Catalina update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375881/touch-bar-has-blank-void-button-after-catalina-update)

Also, booting to recovery mode / internet recovery should let you know if reinstalling the os on top of your apps and data is worthwhile.