# Macbook, put a few buttons on the right side of touchbar

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I currently have only `esc` button on touchbar.

Because I keep pressing touchbar above number 3, 4, I disabled them all.

Since I'm not touching right side of touchbar by mistake, I'd like to put some buttons on the right side.

It seemed `space` in the touchbar seemed to work as a `space` between `esc` and some button on the right I'd like to put (maybe volume controls)

But I can't drag `space` onto touchbar, it just gets deleted.

So Can I have `esc` on the left, and `volume` button on the right and nothing inbetween on touchbar?

Comment: Like this, have you logged out of your account, shut down the Mac and then done a start up from off? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375881/touch-bar-has-blank-void-button-after-catalina-update

Comment: I haven't had a chance to reboot.. so the `space` can do what I think it can do?